# Is there an existing equivalent to \boxed for outside math mode?

Tags: math-mode, tcolorbox

I was wondering if there is an equivalent to `\boxed` for use outside of math mode? One that renders exactly the same. We can use libraries like tcolorbox to create a similar box, but I cannot seem to get it to look exactly the same.

Comment: Can you explain with an example what you have (with boxed and tcolorbox) and what, exactly, that you are missing?

Comment: `\fbox{...}` is the answer

Answer (score 3):

If you do from a terminal

```bash
latexdef -s -p amsmath boxed
```

you get the answer

```
% amsmath.sty, line 400:
\DeclareRobustCommand{\boxed}[1]{\fbox{\m@th$\displaystyle#1$}}
```

You see that `\boxed` is defined using `\fbox`. There are a couple of quirks, namely `\m@th` that avoids unwanted spaces in case the document sets `\mathsurround` to a positive value; also the math style is set to `\displaystyle`.

What you want is `\fbox`, that's described in every basic manual of LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

`fbox` looks pretty much the same.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\(\boxed{E = mc^2}\)
\fbox{\(E = mc^2\)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The only visible difference is in the placement of the exponent, `2`: It's placed ever so slightly higher on the left, i.e., in the `\boxed` case.

Comment: @Mico that's `\displaystyle`